# "Saluditos, besitos, etc." ¿Cómo se llama este diminutivo?

Tags: diminutivos

Por ejemplo en *besitos*. El diminutivo no indica que los besos son pequeños, sino que denota un estado anímico alegre.

¿Tiene este tipo de diminutivo un nombre técnico?

Comment: [_Sufijo de valor diminutivo o afectivo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MEbj2r3), dice la RAE

Comment: @fedorqui - Te invito a hacer una respuesta.  Tanto la respuesta de rodrigo como tu aportación me parecen bien.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tal vez te sirva la categoría [**apreciativos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3IBjZKk)

> **2**. adj. Gram. Dicho de un sufijo: Que expresa una valoración afectiva de lo denotado por el vocablo al que se une. U. m. c. s. m.

aunque tiene el problema de que no hay mucho acuerdo con respecto a qué son, gramaticalmente hablando.

Una visión, la que conocía yo, indica que son morfemas (normalmente sufijos) que agregan algún valor emotivo a otro morfema (una palabra base). Vale decir, serían otra categoría junto a los diminutivos. Por lo tanto, *-ito* a veces es un diminutivo (*piedrita*) y otras veces es un apreciativo (*amorcito*).

Pero ahora leo que hay [otra visión](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Apreciativos), parece que predominante, que agrupa a los diminutivos, aumentativos y despectivos bajo la categoría superior de apreciativos. (Si es así, entonces mi respuesta no es lo que buscas, aunque espero que en algo te sirva).

Una sugerencia: el diminutivo no *denota un estado de ánimo*, sino que lo *connota*.